# Windows 10: make network discovery stay on

Tags: wireless-networking, home-networking

If I restart the PC or disable then enable the network adapter, the network discovery is turned off. I have to turn it on manually. Is there a way to make it stay on? This is a wireless connection to a home LAN, a private network.

Answer (score 0):

> Windows lets you set each network you connect to as either a “Private”
>   or “Public” network.
>
> On Private networks, Windows enables network discovery features. Other
>   devices can see your Windows computer on the network, allowing for
>   easy file sharing and other networked features. Windows will also use
>   the Homegroup feature to share files and media between your PCs.
>
> On Public networks–like those in coffee shops–you don’t want your
>   computer to be seen by others, though, or share your files with them.
>   So Windows turns off these discovery features. it won’t appear to
>   other devices on the network and won’t try to discover them. Even if
>   you’ve set up a Homegroup on your PC, it won’t be enabled on a public
>   network.
>
> It’s simple, really. Windows assumes that your private networks–like
>   your home or work networks–are trusted networks full of other devices
>   you may want to connect to. Windows assumes that public networks are
>   full of other people’s devices you don’t want to connect to, so it
>   uses different settings.
>   More on [howtogeek.com](https://www.howtogeek.com/245982/whats-the-difference-between-private-and-public-networks-in-windows/).

Try the following:

1. Open **GpEdit.msc** *(Group Policy editor)*
2. Under **Computer Configuration**, expand **Windows Settings** folder inside it expand **Security Settings** and there You will see the **Network List Manager Policies** folder
3. Right click on **Network List Manager Policies** folder and from the menu, choose "Show all networks"
4. Inside **Network List Manager Policies** folder, *on the right side*, you will see your networks. To access their properties, right click on the desired network, and in the menu choose "**Properties**".
5. Inside the **Network properties** window switch to the "**Network location**" tab and set the **Location type** to **Private**. If You are having a hard time to pinpoint the desired network, do this for all Networks that are shown there(it's not smartest thing to do, but it should do the trick).

[image]

Or You could do the following:

1. Navigate to **Advanced sharing settings**:
   "Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network and Sharing Center\Advanced sharing settings"
2. Expand **Guest or Public** tab and select **Turn on network discovery**
3. Click on **Save changes**
   Then your network dicovery will be turned on all the time(again, not the smartest thing)

[image]

Comment: I did set it up as a private network. Yet, network discovery gets turned off quite often.

Comment: So your WiFi network stays in(declared as) Private profile, but her Network discovery setting switch to TURNED OFF state?

Comment: Yes. I'm not quite sure when the Network Discovery would be turned off. Sometimes, when I boot up my laptop, it's already off. Sometimes, if I switched to another router and back, it's off.

Comment: I think my network adapter is at fault. From time to time, it'd disconnect from the network.